# How to return the inner fields at same level in Spring Boot?

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to return the class at the same level here.

As here id, username, password, etc are under **userCredentialEntity** and so in **userDetailEntity** key.

```
{
  "userCredentialsEntity": {
    "id": 5,
    "username": "testuser3",
    "password": "$2a$10$yFmeUcE3uTOf9H4TZqWXfO/b8zsTp6sqnWax5iyRXBhlfXF3dSsk2",
    "email": "testuser3@gmail.com",
    "roles": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "ROLE_MANAGER"
      }
    ]
  },
  "userDetailsEntity": {
    "userId": 5,
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "Singh 3",
    "birth_date": "12",
    "birth_month": "01",
    "birth_year": "2002",
    "area": "Chandani Chowk",
    "city": "Sahadra",
    "district": "Sonbhadra",
    "pin_code": 231325,
    "mobile_number": "6788762345"
  }
}
```

I have to return this.

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "username": "testuser3",
    "email": "testuser3@gmail.com",
    "roles": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "ROLE_MANAGER"
        }
    ],
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "Singh 3",
    "birth_date": "12",
    "birth_month": "01",
    "birth_year": "2002",
    "area": "Chandani Chowk",
    "city": "Sahadra",
    "district": "Sonbhadra",
    "pin_code": 231325,
    "mobile_number": "6788762345"
}
```

**And also neglect the password and userId field while returning**

The Code for my implementation is:

```
@Data
public class UserMerged {
    private UserCredentialsEntity userCredentialsEntity;
    private UserDetailsEntity userDetailsEntity;
}
```

```
UserDetailsEntity userDetailsEntity = userDetailService.fetchUserDetails(userId).get();
UserCredentialsEntity userCredentialsEntity = userCredentialsRepository.findByUsername(username);
UserMerged userMerged = new UserMerged();
userMerged.setUserDetailsEntity(userDetailsEntity);
userMerged.setUserCredentialsEntity(userCredentialsEntity);
return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userMerged);
```

I am new in Spring Boot and doesn't got any satisfactory answer regarding this. Please suggest me any way of achieving this.
Thank You.

Comment: Create the proper data structure for it. Your `UserMerged` should represent the return type you want, currently it doesn't, so what would you expect otherwise? Change your `UserMerged` to what you need it to be and map the fields from the entity correctly to those fields.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But if there are too much fields in userCredentials as well as in userDetails, then I have to repeat that again. What to do in that case?

Comment: Repeat what? You just need to create an object that represents your wanted result and copy from those other objects to the object you want.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, Whatever your return type of object is, for that you need to create the specific class and then return it.

In your case Modify your `UserMerged` class with whatever u would like to return and then set the parameters accordingly.

Likely,

Your `UserMerged` will be

```
@Data
public class UserMerged {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer Id;

@Column(name="username")
private String username;    

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@Column(name="roles")
private List<Roles> roles;  

@Column(name="first_name")
private String first_name;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String last_name;

@Column(name="birth_date")
private String birth_date;

@Column(name="birth_month")
private String birth_month;

@Column(name="birth_year")
private String birth_year;

@Column(name="area")
private String area;

@Column(name="city")
private String city;

@Column(name="district")
private String district;

@Column(name="pin_code")
private Integer pin_code;

@Column(name="mobile_number")
private Integer mobile_number;
```

And instead of setting the `UserDetailsEntity` and `UserCredentialsEntity` you can set your fields from those two classes to `UserMerged` class.

```
    userMerged.setId(userCredentialsEntity.getId());
    userMerged.setUsername(userCredentialsEntity.getUsername());
    userMerged.setEmail(userCredentialsEntity.getEmail());
    userMerged.setRoles(userCredentialsEntity.getRoles());
    userMerged.setFirst_name(userDetailsEntity.getFirst_name());
    userMerged.setLast_name(userDetailsEntity.getLast_name());
    userMerged.setBirth_date(userDetailsEntity.getBirth_date());
    userMerged.setBirth_month(userDetailsEntity.getBirth_month());
    userMerged.setBirth_year(userDetailsEntity.getBirth_year());
    userMerged.setArea(userDetailsEntity.getArea());
    userMerged.setCity(userDetailsEntity.getCity());
    userMerged.setDistrict(userDetailsEntity.getDistrict());
    userMerged.setPin_code(userDetailsEntity.getPin_code());
    userMerged.setMobile_number(userDetailsEntity.getMobile_number());
```

This will set all parameters you needed, and you can return the object of **user merged** object.

Here Their is lot much repetation of code exist so instead so please take care of that or you can also add common parameters into one class.